# Editable jquery datatable with sql database

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, datatables

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'EmployeeService.asmx/GetEmployees',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#datatable').dataTable({
                        data: data,
                        columns: [
                            { 'data': 'Id' },
                            { 'data': 'userID' },
                            { 'data': 'userPassword' },
                            { 'data': 'userEmail' },
                            { 'data': 'userIsActiv' },
                        ]
                    });
                }
            });
        });

    </script>
```

```html
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server" method="post">
        <table id="datatable">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Id</th>
                    <th>userID</th>
                    <th>userPassword</th>
                    <th>userEmail</th>
                    <th>userIsActiv</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
        <div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

I have a Jquery datatable which displays the data fetched from SQL database from Web service EmployeeService.asmx/GetEmployees.

I need to make this datatable to be editable like double click any column in any row, then I can edit the data like the datatable in the following link.

https://editor.datatables.net/examples/inline-editing/simple

How can I make the datatable editable like that so that after the editing the data will be updated correctly to the database?

Comment: Try to implement the code demonstrated by this gentleman https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/165410/ASP-NET-MVC-Editable-DataTable-jQuery-DataTables-a